# php bin2hex problem

Tags: php, hex, character

I Wrote a small php script to convert string to HEX 
but i have a problem or i missed something , Here is a small test :

```
$char='だ';
$a='a';
echo $char,':', bin2hex($char),"\n";
echo $a,':', bin2hex($a),"\n";
```

The result i get for the 'a' (or any ASCII) is correct but for Chinese or Hebrew or Arabic are 
not correct Here is the output:

```
だ:e381a0
a:61
```

What is this long number the HEX for this char(だ) from charmap tool is 3060
but why i get wrong values from PHP.

Thanks.

Comment: FYI, this is Japanese character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0xE381A0` is the UTF-8 encoding for `だ`:

```
U+3060  だ   e3 81 a0    HIRAGANA LETTER DA
```

http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=12192

So your output is correct if your input is supposed to be UTF-8.

## Update

If that's what you want, you can obtain `3060` with any of these:

```
iconv_set_encoding('internal_encoding', 'UTF-8');

echo bin2hex(iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-10646-UCS-2', 'だ')) . PHP_EOL;
echo bin2hex(iconv('UTF-8', 'UNICODE-1-1', 'だ')) . PHP_EOL;
echo bin2hex(iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-16BE', 'だ')) . PHP_EOL;
```

See [iconv()](http://php.net/iconv) for further info.

Comment: I see,so is there a way to get the hex value from the UTF-8 encoding?.Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question. In what way does it need to be more hex than `e381a0`?

Comment: i mean how to get the '3060' .

Comment: @ibmkhd Even if my answer was of any help, I recommend you redesign the feature so it doesn't depend on manually hard-coded hexadecimal numbers. PHP is not the nicest lang to handle Unicode but it does have some built-in abilities you can benefit from.

Answer (score 0):

- e3 = 227
- 81 = 129
- a0 = 160

That's probably a 3-byte Unicode character, hence the three hex values returned by `bin2hex()`. See this phpsh output if you're still confused:

```
php> =bin2hex('adam')
"6164616d"
```

Comment: But how i get the correct hex value,the charmap tool returned 3060 for this char ,i need a way to get the same value from PHP. And i get also the same with Arabic .

Comment: I don't think there is a "correct hex value." You could add up those three hex numbers, but e381a0 is a different character from a081e3, and they both have the same sum. Unless you say `0xE3 + 0x81 * 16 + 0xA0 * 16 * 16`. Are you trying to get PHP to give you the same value as charmap?

Comment: @ibmkhd, are you trying to convert from UTF-8 to another charset?

Comment: NO ,i need to check a string if it contains invalid character.so i compare each character in the string with a range of hex so i need to convert the character to hex before comparing.              if($char >= 0x20 && $char<=0x7e)....

Comment: @imbkhd I recommend you update your question. If you want to filter a range of Unicode characters, you're more likely to get a quality answer if you ask that question directly.

Comment: @ibmkhd The question "test if a character is valid in a given charset" is entirely different... There are functions for that, such as `mb_check_encoding()`.